# How to have only 1 completion handler for 2 Alamofire request in the same function

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, completionhandler

I have a function with 2 Alamofire requests inside with a completion handler. I want to reload my collectionView once I have both requests completed downloading data from server. I have a completion handler in the function but it gets called twice which causes my collectionView reload twice and I would love to reload only one time. Is there a way that I can do so? Thank you so much!

```
func getFeedVideos(completion: @escaping (_ completedDownloadVideo: Bool) -> ()){

    Alamofire.request(youTubeUrl, method: .get, parameters: ["part":"snippet","maxResults": "20","nextPageToken" : "pageToken", "playlistId": playListId, "key": googleAPIKey], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
        guard let data = response.data else {return}
        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(serverData.self, from: data)
            self.dataFromAPI = json.items
            completion(true)
        } catch let jsonErr{
            print(jsonErr)
        }
    }

    Alamofire.request(youTubeChannelUrl, method: .get, parameters: ["part":"snippet", "key": googleAPIKey, "id": youTubeChannelId], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
        guard let data = response.data else {return}
        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(channelInfo.self, from: data)
            self.channelData = json.items
            completion(true)
        } catch let jsonErr{
            print(jsonErr)
        }
    }
}
```

and here is how I called the function in ViewDidLoad

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getFeedVideos { (complete) in
        if complete{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `getFeedVideos` method as shown below:

```
func getFeedVideos(completion: @escaping (_ completedDownloadVideo: Bool) -> ()){

    Alamofire.request(youTubeUrl, method: .get, parameters: ["part":"snippet","maxResults": "20","nextPageToken" : "pageToken", "playlistId": playListId, "key": googleAPIKey], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
        guard let data = response.data else {return}
        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(serverData.self, from: data)
            self.dataFromAPI = json.items

            Alamofire.request(youTubeChannelUrl, method: .get, parameters: ["part":"snippet", "key": googleAPIKey, "id": youTubeChannelId], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
                guard let data = response.data else {return}
                do {
                    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(channelInfo.self, from: data)
                    self.channelData = json.items
                    completion(true)
                } catch let jsonErr{
                    print(jsonErr)
                }
            }
        } catch let jsonErr{
            print(jsonErr)
        }
    }
}
```

As I am seeing in your code you are calling `completion(true)` in both API calls thats why its reloading multiple times. In my code I have replaced `completion(true)` from your first API call with another API call so Once your both API call with complete your `completion(true)` will call.

Hope this will help.

**Note:**

Didn't checked this code on Xcode so let me know if you got any issue with this code.

Comment: It works! I just need to put self for reference inside 2nd request call. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

A Better solution

Use `DispatchGroup` Here is example

```
   let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter()

Alamofire.request(youTubeUrl, method: .get, parameters: ["part":"snippet","maxResults": "20","nextPageToken" : "pageToken", "playlistId": playListId, "key": googleAPIKey], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
        guard let data = response.data else {return}
        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(serverData.self, from: data)
            self.dataFromAPI = json.items
            completion(true)
        } catch let jsonErr{
            print(jsonErr)
        }
      dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

 dispatchGroup.enter()

    Alamofire.request(youTubeChannelUrl, method: .get, parameters: ["part":"snippet", "key": googleAPIKey, "id": youTubeChannelId], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
        guard let data = response.data else {return}
        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(channelInfo.self, from: data)
            self.channelData = json.items
            completion(true)
        } catch let jsonErr{
            print(jsonErr)
        }
       dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
```

Here is magic lines

```
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("Both functions complete ")
}
```

> Each call to enter() must be matched later on with a call to leave(), after which the group will call the closure provided to notify().

Comment: @kevinvu Happy to help :)